# Custom indexOf() without String methods

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, strings, search

I created my own `indexOf` function. I was wondering if anyone could help me come up with a way to make it more efficient. I am practicing for interviews so the catch is that I cannot use any `String` methods. I believe the runtime of this method is O(n<sup>2</sup>) with space of O(n). Correct me if I am wrong.

Also, I want to ensure the program runs safely and correctly, the only test case I can think of it the length comparison.

```
public static int myIndexOf(char[] str, char[] substr) {
    int len = str.length;
    int sublen = substr.length;
    int count = 0;
            if (sublen > len) {
                return -1;
            }
    for (int i = 0; i < len - sublen + 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sublen; j++) {
            if (str[j+i] == substr[j]) {
                count++;
                if (count == sublen) {
                    return i;
                }
            } else {
                count = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Wikipedia has a list of string substring searching algorithms with their time and space complexity. The faster it goes, the more complicated (and cool and innovative!) it is, but knowing the internals of a nice and fast one could be something to talk about in an interview, perhaps? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a problem in your code and this hilights it :

```
class Class_Test {

    public static int myIndexOf(char[] str, char[] substr) {
        int len = str.length;
        int sublen = substr.length;
        int count = 0;
        if (sublen > len) {
            return -1;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < len - sublen + 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < sublen; j++) {
                if (str[j+i] == substr[j]) {
                    count++;
                    if (count == sublen) {
                        return i;
                    }
                } else {
                    count = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static boolean compareFunc(String s1, String s2)
    {
        int r1 = s1.indexOf(s2);
        int r2 = myIndexOf(s1.toCharArray(), s2.toCharArray());
        boolean ret = (r1==r2);
        System.out.println(ret + " for '" + s1 + "' '" + s2 + "' -> " + r1 + " " + r2);
        return ret;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        // Empty string
        compareFunc("", "");
        compareFunc("A", "");
        compareFunc("AB", "");
        compareFunc("", "A");
        compareFunc("", "AB");
        // Equal non-empty strings
        compareFunc("A", "A");
        compareFunc("AB", "AB");
        compareFunc("ABC", "A");
        // Match at the beginning
        compareFunc("A", "AB");
        compareFunc("AB", "ABC");
        compareFunc("ABC", "ABD");
        // Match at the end
        compareFunc("B", "AB");
        compareFunc("BC", "ABC");
        compareFunc("ABC", "DBC");
        // Match at the middle
        compareFunc("BC", "ABCD");
        compareFunc("CD", "ABCDEF");
        // No match on longer strings
        compareFunc("QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKL", "ZXCVBNM");
        compareFunc("ZXCVBNM","QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKL");
        System.out.println("Test successful");
    }
}
```

Good reviews have been given and I have nothing to add.

Edit : additional details for what it is worth :

- an additional test case should be added to check that *first* occurence is found
- your implementation corresponds to the naive way of searching. In the litterature, you'll find [other algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm) with potentially better performances.

Comment: Good spotting... for what it is worth, I have never been certain I like the `String.indexOf("")` handling in Java....

Comment: Your answer goes through all tests properly so you implicitly agree with this behavior  ;-) (and have my +1)

Comment: I think some of the test cases are switched around. The ones that are commented with a match, do not match.

Comment: Well I'm not quite sure what you mean but in any case, your function should probably have a behaviour as close as possible to the original method. Let me know (or fell free to edit my answer) if there is anything wrong.

Comment: @Josay sorry I wasn't clear. What I meant was in your test cases, `compareFunc("BC", "ABCD");` I think you meant `compareFunc("ABCD", "BC");`? Because there isn't an actual match in any of the middle, beginning, and end cases you provided. I am assuming this is what you wanted to do.

Comment: In right, indeed. I'll fix this in a couple of hours. Thanks for spotting :-)

Answer (score 31):

### Complexity

Pedantically, the time-complexity is \$ O( m \times n ) \$, where `m` is `str.length` and `n` is `substr.length`. This matters when \$ \left| m-n \right| \$ is large.

The Space complexity is \$ O(1) \$. You do not allocate any size-based memory structures.

### Safety

It all looks good. There are no threading issues, no leaks, no problems.

### Correctly

Nope, I don't like the lack of neat handling for invalid inputs.... you should be null-checking, etc. Getting a raw 'NullPointerException' looks bad.

Edit: *Note that* [Josay has pointed out](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/44107/31503) that your code (and my code below) produce different behaviour to `String.indexOf()` when the search term is the empty-string/empty-array.

### Alternative

I think your code is fine, but... I tend to use loop break/continue more than most... and, this saves a bunch of code in this case...

Also, for readability, I often introduce a `limit` variable when the loop-terminator can be complicated....

Consider the following loops which do not need the `count` variable:

```
int limit = len - sublen + 1;
searchloop: for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < sublen; j++) {
        if (str[j+i] != substr[j]) {
            continue searchloop;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
return -1;
```

Answer (score 15):

One thing which does not seem to have been mentioned in other answers,

```
for (int i = 0; i < len - sublen + 1; i++) {
```

Instead of checking **less than** x **plus one**. You can do *less than **or equal to*** x.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= len - sublen; i++) {
```

I find this a bit easier to read and understand.

This can also be applied to the monkey's (@rolfl's) code:

```
int limit = len - sublen;
searchloop: for (int i = 0; i <= limit; i++) {
...
```

Answer (score 13):

This looks good to me.

For efficiency, you have two options:

1. Reduce the number of operations in the inner loop. Let's look at that.

   ```
   for (int j = 0; j < sublen; j++) {
       if (str[j+i] == substr[j]) {
           count++;
           if (count == sublen) {
               return i;
           }
       ...
   }
   ```

   Here, the addition `j+i` seems like something you should be able to, somehow, replace with a single initial addition outside the loop, and an increment inside the loop. There also seems to be correlation between `j` and `count` (if anyone which line you are on, you'll have either `count == j` or `count == j+1`. It follows that the test `j < sublen` is false if and only if `count == sublen` it true, so you could probably get rid of one of them.

   At this point I want to emphasise that this kind of analysis will give you performance increases so small that they are almost certainly not worth the effort. That leads us to:
2. Look for a different algorithm. This is likely the only way to get a significant increase in performance. A good place to start is the classical Boyer-Moore algorithm.

   For complexity, recall the inputs:

   ```
   public static int myIndexOf(char[] str, char[] substr)
   ```

   If `str` is of length n and `substr` is of length m, your implementation executes the outer loop roughly n times and, in the worst case, each of those n iterations executes the inner loop m times. The running time of your implementation is thus no worse than O(n*m).

   When considering space complexity, one should not count the space used for inputs, only the *additional* space used.  Your implementation uses only a fixed number of variables (`len, sublen, count, i`) of primitive type. The amount of space it uses is independent of the sizes n and m of the input strings, and so we say that your implementation uses "constant space", written O(1).

   Finally, I want to mention that your implementation is not far from the actual implementation of the Java standard library; check it out [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/String.java#String.indexOf%28java.lang.String%2Cint%29).

Comment: I wish Java had an array type which could be read and written as 1, 2, 4, or 8 byte values; many kinds of string-related algorithms could benefit from processing things in multi-character chunks, even if one would have to use special-case logic for different alignments, and to handle the starting and ending bits of a string (e.g. to look for the string "ABRACADABRA", start by examining every other 64-bit word, ignoring everything that isn't ABRA, CADA, BRAC, ADAB, RACA, DABR, or ACAD).  Either endianness could be simulated at a cost of at most one extra instruction per access.

Answer (score 9):

Other answers are already covering what maybe matters more to you: space, time complexity, safety, correctness. I think you can do further steps in order to improve the code readability: if it was a production code it would be hard to maintain. Consider the following suggestions:

- variables should go nearest their utilization as possible: avoid broad global declaration as far as you can;

  - for example, why is `count` initialized before the first exit point, that is where it could never be used? It should go just before the for instruction (the first for? - on a first reading I couldn't say it)
- `len - sublen + 1` should be stored in a final variable (constant) with a good name: what does it mean that value?
- the default return value (`-1`) should be declared in one point, with a meaningful name (no magic numbers). What if later you would want to change the default not-found value?
- the function has three exit points, with a further `break` in a nested loop, causing  a difficult reading of its logical branches (they remember insane `goto`s)
- the main exit point `count == sublen` should go inside a meaningful boolean variable: why is this an exit condition? How would you explain it to your coworker?

If you want to see a different approach to `indexOf` (but on byte arrays) you could check the following code, with also should be more readable:

```
    public static int search(byte[] input, byte[] searchedFor) {
        //convert byte[] to Byte[]
        Byte[] searchedForB = new Byte[searchedFor.length];
        for(int x = 0; x<searchedFor.length; x++){
            searchedForB[x] = searchedFor[x];
        }

        int idx = -1;

        //search:
        Deque<Byte> q = new ArrayDeque<Byte>(input.length);
        for(int i=0; i<input.length; i++){
            if(q.size() == searchedForB.length){
                //here I can check
                Byte[] cur = q.toArray(new Byte[]{});
                if(Arrays.equals(cur, searchedForB)){
                    //found!
                    idx = i - searchedForB.length;
                    break;
                } else {
                    //not found
                    q.pop();
                    q.addLast(input[i]);
                }
            } else {
                q.addLast(input[i]);
            }
        }

        return idx;
    }
```

([Original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22234021/search-for-a-string-as-an-byte-in-a-binary-stream/22236277#22236277))

Comment: This is not really a code review answer, is it? At least you should explain in how far the code would help to improve the ops code.

Comment: I proposed it because I think it is more readable. What do you mean by "ops code"? And where can I find code review's rules? Thanks

Comment: With "ops" I meant "OP's" (Original Poster's). There are [some discussions on meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/913/30346) around what a good code review is. Basically your answer would be more useful if you include some explanation of why and how your version is more readable.

Comment: I've just updated the answer with my considerations on code readability - I hope I made my point clearer, thanks for your feedbacks